# How fix error message "Unable to load custom class 'GameScene' from module '(null)'" Xcode in console

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit

when I work in Xcode with SpriteKit and use simulator or even real iPhone its always show this message beneath, the app not crash but still this message appear even if I open new fresh SpritKit fill.

Unable to load custom class 'GameScene' from module '(null)'

Answer (score 2):

In Xcode project, go to GameScene.sks and in Custom Class Inspector make sure the Custom Class name is "GameScene" and Module is empty.

[image]

Comment: I did that and is still same problem happened.

Comment: Are you sure you load it correctly? Try this approach let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene"). Also make sure you did the previous step I told before/

Comment: The error message is gone after I remove the name of class from "Custom Class", I think this problem happened  because I make many  GameScene.sks and never use them cause I write the entire scene by code and never use GameScene.sks to add elements to the scene, after I remove all the scene and just use the original one the error message is finally gone.

Comment: In that case create new scenes like this let scene = GameScene(), let scene = MainScene(), etc.

Comment: Ok I did that and the massage is gone, But this massage is appear : SKView: ignoreRenderSyncInLayoutSubviews is NO. Call _renderSynchronouslyForTime without handler

Comment: You will get this warning if you have UIKit subviews of the SKView. If you create an empty project in Xcode, you will also get this error. But since it doesn't affect your game in any way and you can ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was linked to a quote (') in the project name, removing it fixed the problem